# Is Entrypoint command executed when a dockerfile is built

Tags: docker, cmd, dockerfile, entry-point

I would expect docker not to execute entrypoint or cmd commands when you are just building a dockerfile. Is this true or not?

Comment: None of them is being executed at `build` stage

Answer (score 0):

nope, neither commands are executed during build, if you do want to run a command during build you should use the RUN keyword.